# Child div not inlining inside parent div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I must be doing something stupid or looking over something obvious, because no matter what I do I cannot get these three `div`s inline inside this parent.

```css
.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.separator {
  background: rgba(47, 187, 255, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 124, 184, 0.7);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <div class="points"><b>Lorem </b>&nbsp; 142</pdiv>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="luck"><b>Ipsum</b>&nbsp; 64% <i>Blabla 3</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/a6t7zr4z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `float:left;` to the .stats div-children.

```css
.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.stats div{
  float:left;
}
.separator {
  background: rgba(47, 187, 255, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 124, 184, 0.7);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <div class="points"><b>Lorem </b>&nbsp; 142</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="luck"><b>Ipsum</b>&nbsp; 64% <i>Blabla 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly for my situation, I know Mehdi's answer would also work however it did not in the way I set up my CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set display: inline (or inline-block) to the children, not the parent :

```css
.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.stats div {
  display: inline;
}
.separator {
  background: rgba(47, 187, 255, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 124, 184, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <div class="points"><b>Lorem </b>&nbsp; 142</pdiv>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="luck"><b>Ipsum</b>&nbsp; 64% <i>Blabla 3</div>
</div>
```

Edit: I also removed the float: left on separator.

Comment: Ah duh! Silly me, I feel bad for asking such a silly question like this. Thank you so much for your help. Edit: That separator has a float:left on another area on the page I am working on, I just did .stats .separator {float: none;} to fix that. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Like Gustaf said you can also use float:left instead, just do not forget to clear after it. Feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: I would upvote but I do not sadly have enough rep yet. I edited my above comment by the way.